# rundeck working directory should not be in root

Tags: rundeck

i created a new rundeck environment, but when i want to create a folder using local node i got permission denied, and after i checked working directory is "/" ( root ).
if i check the configuration base directory is "/var/lib/rundeck" and on configuration is no config to using root / as the base working directory.

i try to create job and pwd to check my working directory but its still on / ( root)

[pwd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FY8Sr.png)

is there anything i should add ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem was already reported [here](https://github.com/rundeck/rundeck/issues/4554) a few years ago (and reopened recently). It affects Rundeck instances that use DEB packaging (Debian, Ubuntu, etc).

Just use the complete intended path if you need to use the local filesystem.
This problem ought to be resolved in subsequent releases.

Comment: hi, i also followed your case in that link, thanks in advance.